# The revenge.xml generated by NetBean for Hibernate doesn't include association

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans-7

I am new to Hibernate. I have finished [this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html) and I tried to 'generate' my first 
hibernate application.

I created four tables on JDBC, account, course, level, subject.
**course have the references key to account, level and subject.** Then I tried to generate the revenge.xml by NetBean. In the wizard, the tables are related, but the xml generated does not include any association mapping.

[image: wizard]

hibernate.revenge.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-schema="APP"/>
  <table-filter match-name="ACCOUNT"/>
  <table-filter match-name="LEVEL"/>
  <table-filter match-name="COURSE"/>
  <table-filter match-name="SUBJECT"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have associations in the `hibernate.reveng.xml` file.

Your associations are defined in the mapped classes, if you're using hibernate annotations, or in the `hbm` file of every class if your using the classic `XML` mapping.

Comment: may be you are right :) I have added the associations manually